# how to put a container on top of another div

Tags: css, html, mask

I can't figure out why my container is displayed on the bottom of the screen. I know there are two possible questions for this. The best would be: how to make a mask apply to the background image, so I could just stick the image url to the background, and then I could play around with the code on top of that. The other question is: How to make the conatiner div display on top of the background div without absolute positioning. Sorry if that is confusing. Here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
<title> 
Singapore - gallery
</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1.0">
<style>
*  {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#background img {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-mask-image: 
  -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, 
  from(rgba(0,0,0,1)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0))); 
  z-index: -1; 
}

#container {
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 3px solid #eee; 
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="background"> <img src="gallery.jpg" />
<div id="container">
<h1> Singapore Gallery </h1>  
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic goes like this

Make the parent div `position: relative;` and make the overlay div as `position: absolute;` and use `top: 0;`

So here you are using `img` tag certainly with no positioning so what you do is

I assume you want to overlay `h1` on your `img` so use `position: relative` for `#background`, than use `position: absolute;` for `img` and make it `top: 0;` and `z-index: 1; /*Optional*/`, and later make `#container` as `position: absolute;` and use `top: 0;` and `z-index: 999; /*Compulsory*/`

Comment: Thanks! I did use your advice for the position absolute top 0 in the #background img, but I put the z-index at -1, than I didn't need to do anything to the conatiner div

Comment: @user1815176 depends on what approach you want to go for, it was good that you understood what I explained you :)